# error to install chronium : packages contain unsatisfied dependencies: libc6-dev: Break: libgcc-8-dev (<8.4.0-2 ~) but 8.3.0-6 must be installed

Tags: google-chrome, raspberry-pi

i have look on this website how to install chronium: i have follow the instruction on this site https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/google-chrome-for-raspberry-pi/ but there is an error when i do this line `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser --yes`

*the original text of the error*

```
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 libc6-dev : Casse: libgcc-8-dev (< 8.4.0-2~) mais 8.3.0-6 devra être installé
E: Erreur, pkgProblem::Resolve a généré des ruptures, ce qui a pu être causé par les paquets devant être gardés en l'état.
```

*the text with traduction of the error*

```
The following packages contain unsatisfied dependencies:
 libc6-dev: Break: libgcc-8-dev (<8.4.0-2 ~) but 8.3.0-6 must be installed
E: Error, pkgProblem :: Resolve generated breaks, which could be caused by the packages that need to be kept as they are.
```

Comment: thanks for helping and solving the problem